# facebook invite friends and login in sprite kit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, facebook, facebook-invite-friends

I have a sprite kit game where i want to implement the feature to invite friends using Facebook. It should be similar to games like candy crush saga where there is a way to invite users through Facebook. I am looking at the tutorial provided by Facebook on how to do so but it is not specific to sprite kit. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial . Can someone suggest me some tutorial or guidance on how to achieve Facebook sharing.

Comment: That tutorial is specific to iOS objective-c, hence on specific event over Sprite Kit you require to call a normal objective-c function which will call Facebook API's sendRequest function. The same tutorial is enough and very well explained each details.

Comment: The only thing i am unsure of is using cpp in sprite kit. Is it okay to use the cpp classes provided in this sample directly in sprite kit project?

Comment: You can have normal function communications in-between CPP-ObjectiveC. Give a try with normal functions in both files, and try calling each other. Then debug using console logs or breakpoints.